# bash: cURL from a file, increment filename if duplicate exists

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to curl a list of URLs to aggregate the tabular data on them from a set of 7000+ URLs. The URLs are in a .txt file. My goal was to cURL each line and save them to a local folder after which I would grep and parse out the HTML tables.

Unfortunately, because of the format of the URLs in the file, duplicates exist (example.com/State/City.html. When I ran a short while loop, I got back fewer than 5500 files, so there are at least 1500 dupes in the list. As a result, I tried to grep the "/State/City.html" section of the URL and pipe it to sed to remove the / and substitute a hyphen to use with curl -O. cURL was trying to grab

Here's a sample of what I tried:

```
while read line
do
    FILENAME=$(grep -o -E '\/[A-z]+\/[A-z]+\.htm' | sed 's/^\///' | sed 's/\//-/')
    curl $line -o '$FILENAME'
done < source-url-file.txt
```

It feels like I'm missing something fairly straightforward. I've scanned the man page because I worried I had confused -o and -O which I used to do a lot.

When I run the loop in the terminal, the output is:

Warning: Failed to create the file State-City.htm

Comment: That's not the full stderr output, we need the following messages as well in order to help you

Comment: Ah, good point @DrewBeres. I'd give you the rest of the error, but I accidentally spilled beer on my laptop and killed it. All I can remember what that there were other filenames like "Nevada-LasVegas.html" followed by a couple of newlines. Sorry, I'm sure that's not that helpful, but my backup is a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you dont need multitude seds and grep, just 1 sed should suffice

```
urls=$(echo -e 'example.com/s1/c1.html\nexample.com/s1/c2.html\nexample.com/s1/c1.html')

for u in $urls
do
  FN=$(echo "$u" | sed -E 's/^(.*)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)$/\2-\3/')
  if [[ ! -f "$FN" ]]
  then
    touch "$FN"
    echo "$FN"
  fi
done
```

This script should work and also take care of downloading same files multiple files.

just replace the `touch` command by your `curl` one

Answer (score 0):

First: you didn't pass the url info to grep.

Second: try this line instead:

```
 FILENAME=$(echo $line | egrep -o '\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\.html' | sed 's/^\///' | sed 's/\//-/')
```